# How can I ALTER COLUMN to NULL when the column in NOT NULL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, alter-column

How can I `ALTER COLUMN` to NULL when the column in NOT NULL in Oracle, with a sentence or script?

Comment: sorry, te correct are: "How can I ALTER COLUMN to NULL when the column IS NOT NULL in Oracle [...]"

Comment: I solved using "Alter table mytable modify column1 VARCHAR2(15) null;"

Answer (score 1):

To alter the column (assuming the current type is `varchar2(100)`):

```
alter table mytable modify column1 varchar2(100) null
```

Interestingly, this fails if the column is *already* nullable.

Comment: I solved using "Alter table mytable modify column1 VARCHAR2(15) null;"